# Microservice architecture for uploading and downloading multiple files at once

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, microservices

I'm trying to create a new microservice with Spring Boot for uploading and downloading multiple files at once.
These files (PDF,XML,ZIP,TIFF,..), based on some conditions, can be stored inside a storage like S3 or inside another kind of storage. This microservice has to implement the logic to understand where these files are, download them temporarily in a local folder and then return them back to the client application.
The goal is to hide the recovery logic and the type of storage where the files reside to the client applications.

Each one of my business entity has several files associated so for the upload API I was thinking of using a Multipart Request to send the files of the same entity all together.
I would like to do the same for the download API: given the ID of an entity the API has to return all the files associated with it.

I don't know what's the best way to achieve this goal.
I have seen that there is a Multipart Response but I don't know if it is reliable.
Another idea is to download the files in a temporary shared folder and to send back to the client application the list of paths where they are.
Another one is to download always the files in a local (not shared) folder and to send back to the client application the list of URLs that it has to use to get them.

What do you think about it? Any other option?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd probably zip up the related files and send them back as one archive.

Comment: I have considered also this solution but I think that it will decrease a lot the performance of the API.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to hide the fact that you're using S3 as the storage backing, my guess is that you're trying to either a) ensure you have the flexibility to change the storage backend at a later date, and/or b) put your own authentication in front of the upload/download to ensure users have permissions to read/write contents.

In either case, this sounds like a good job for a performant API gateway to ensure you maximize throughput. Instead of writing a custom service, you can write a configuration for something like Traefik that would a) authenticate requests, b) proxy the request to S3 directly, and c) rewrite the host and path to mask the usage of S3 as a storage backend. If you choose to use Traefik, take a look at the [Routers](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/) section and the [ReplacePathRegex](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/replacepathregex/) middleware.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my use case is a little bit different. 
My files are not all in the S3 storage. They could be in S3 or in another NFS volume so this API has to contain also the logic to find where the requested files are and retrieve them from the correct source.